# Datatables - real-time get data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable, real-time

I have laravel application, where I need to 'listen' database for new/edited records - about 3000 records - in real-time. For display data, I'm using DataTables.
To create this 'real-time', I have 2 ideas:

1) use WebSockets - maybe Socket.io. I will be very grateful for the best option for this solution: Laravel + DataTables. The records contain personal data, so it must be safe.

2) use Ajax and setTimeout(1000) - how much will affect the performance so frequent refresh?

Which way will be better?

Comment: Because i can not fully validate it right now, its just a comment, but i'm pretty sure, socket.io is your way to go, but have in mind, socket.io is a NODE.js application, so you need to communicate somehow between your nodejs app and your php app

Answer (score 0):

Most likely websockets will be the better option, if you desire to have the changes available in the client as soon as possible after detection. Also, it should save you resources as long the changes are less frequent than your polling interval (1000ms in your example).

Laravel 5.3 will support [pusher](https://pusher.com/) out of the box: https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting